# check php session by JavaScript ,if it does not exist should not cause any error

Tags: javascript, php

```
var secret_photo
var secret_name

if (!<?php echo isset($_SESSION['fb_item'])?'true':'false'; ?>) {
if($.cookie("domain[user]")){
secret_photo = 'noavatar.png';
secret_name = 'admin';
}
} else {
secret_photo = <?php echo json_encode($_SESSION['fb_item']['url']); ?>;
secret_name = <?php echo json_encode($_SESSION['fb_item']['name']); ?>;
}
```

I need to set `php` session to `html` using `JavaScript` .There is 2 logins , one is the `facebook` and the other is my own login system, `facebook` uses session and my own login sets cookie.

When I login by `facebook` , things are good , but if I login using my own login system , that echo check is going to cause problem , so how am I going to fix it ? Check if the session is available or not even if it doesn't exist it wont cause any problem.

Comment: Look up how to use Ajax :)

Comment: what error do you get when you login via your login system?

Comment: This is fundamentally wrong: you _cannot_ use php on the client side, so inside javascript!

Comment: I was gonna say that. Do your session checks via php not javascript

Comment: PhpDev yeah if login with my own system it have error , i wanted to check on php , but it delay alot time. is thing wont show.

Answer (score 1):

You are probably encounter an error at the bottom of your code. You can't access `$_SESSION['fb_item']` if it doesn't exist, it either shows a `Notice` or generate wrong js code `secret_photo = ;`. Just move condition to `php` side:

```
var secret_photo
var secret_name

<?php if(!isset($_SESSION['fb_item'])):?>
    if($.cookie("domain[user]")){
        secret_photo = 'noavatar.png';
        secret_name = 'admin';
    }
<?php else:?>
    secret_photo = <?php echo json_encode($_SESSION['fb_item']['url']); ?>;
    secret_name = <?php echo json_encode($_SESSION['fb_item']['name']); ?>;
<?php endif;?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var secret_photo
var secret_name
<?php if(!isset($_SESSION['fb_item'])){?>
    if($.cookie('user')){
        secret_photo = 'noavatar.png';
        secret_name = 'admin';
    }
<?php }else{?>
    secret_photo = <?php echo json_encode($_SESSION['fb_item']['url']); ?>;
    secret_name = <?php echo json_encode($_SESSION['fb_item']['name']); ?>;
<?php }?>
</script>
```